# how to write each Letter in random rotation on the image

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

my code write some letters in image but what I want is to write each letter in random rotation as attached image

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((500,500,3), np.uint8)
char = "ABCDEFG"

for i in range (0,7,1):
    cv2.putText(img, char[i], (150 + i*30, 250), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

#Display the image
cv2.imshow("img",img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

see the image to see what the result that I want:

[image: see the image to see what the result that I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the perfect solution but one way to do it can be as followed.

```py
import numpy as np
import random
import cv2

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((500,500,3), np.uint8)
char = "ABCDEFG"

for i in range (0,7,1):
    text_location = (150 + i*30, 250)   # Location of the letter
    angle = random.randint(0,90)        # angle of rotation

    # Rotate the image to put the letter at an angle
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(text_location, angle, 1)
    img = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))

    # Put the letter.
    cv2.putText(img, char[i], text_location, font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    # Undo the initial rotation of image for the next letter.
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(text_location, -1*angle, 1)
    img = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))

    # Thresholding to keep the image sharp
    (thresh, img) = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#Display the image
cv2.imshow("img",img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

### Output

- Before Thresholding

[image]

- After Thresholding

[image]

#### Note

- The range `[0-90]` gave the best result in my opinion but you can play around with it (Bigger range resulted in overlapping letters, so)
- Also play around with the thresholds for better tuned and desired result in the thresholding step.

Comment: Thank you so much ,,, but why if I make more letter (more range) it is become blur letters?

Comment: @iyad I think it is caused by warpAffine(). I'm looking into various interpolation options it provide, will let you know if I am able to improve the results.

Comment: @iyad So everytime you use warpAffine() to rotate the image at an arbitrary angle (that is not multiple of 90), it usually loose details as now it has to map the pixels of an image which is not perfectly inline with the pixel grid of screen. And as we do the rotation over and over again on the same image, the letters added earliest looses the most amount of details. Luckily as our image is binary(Black and white) it would be fairly easy to get back the details with thresholding after each cycle of rotation.(again not the perfect solution, but it works). I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks guys ...it was so helpful

Comment: @iyad Glad I was helpful. If you feel that it answers your question then please accept it as an answer and give it a green tick.

Comment: you are repeatedly resampling the same image, which causes the progressively worsening blur. that's **bad**. it is entirely avoidable. -- **instead** you should rotate each letter individually, then copy it into the destination.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I know that's why *Not the perfect solution* in the beginning of the answer. It was something I came up with limited research.